# POST image inside FORM tag

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, file-upload

I want to post an entire IMAGE when SUBMIT button is clicked.

```
<FORM action=".." method=post>
        <img src="...."/>
        <input type="submit" value="Click"/>
</FORM>
```

Is it possible?

Please help me......

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Where is the image? If you are using an `<img>` element, then it is presumably "on the Internet" so you are unlikely to benefit from the data in it being submitted back to the server. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: That's not how forms work. They only submit a specific set of tags such as <input> and <select> provided you specify a name attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking to upload an image? If so, then you'll want the "file" HTML `input` element type:

```
<input type="file"/>
```

And include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag.

Here's a basic tutorial and more info:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Comment: my guess is that the OP wants the image to be selected and uploaded with the form automatically, which is not allowed with a `file` for security reasons

Comment: It's possible that's what the OP wants, but it's a somewhat vague question. Doesn't hurt to offer a solution based on an interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to post an image inside a form, you should have that image already on your server.  In which case all you have to do is put a hidden element on the form with the location of that image and voila you have the image in the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="image_location" id="image_location" value="/images/bleh.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<FORM action=".." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" placeholder="upload a file"       
    name="file">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</FORM>
```